# MongoDB - MapReduce with Time Series Bucketing

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, mapreduce, time-series

I have a schema based on a time series bucketing model. I'm now trying to convert some aggregation pipelines toward MapReduce models but i can't figure out what is the equivalant of an "unwind" in MapReduce. Here is my model :

[time series schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNYU.jpg)

For exemple, how can I sum all the values in "val_per_day_dt" per "SITE_ID" ?

Comment: What are you trying to "unwind" ?

Comment: i was trying to unwind the "val_per_day_dt". The solution below works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Using the input document (a short version of the posted image) as follows:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  site_id: "512",
  industry: "Food Sales",
  val_per_day_dt: {
      "2012-04-13 00:05:00": 23.4087,
      "2012-04-13 00:10:00": 26.0463,
      "2012-04-13 00:15:00": 27.3761
  }
}
```

The map and reduce functions:

```
m1 = function() {
        for (let k in this.val_per_day_dt) {
            emit(this.site_id, this.val_per_day_dt[k])
        }
}

r1 = function(k, v) {
         return Array.sum(v);
}
```

Run the `mapReduce` method:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    m1,
    r1,
   { out: "collection_out" }
)
```

The `collection_out` has the following result:

```
{ "_id" : "512", "value" : 76.83109999999999 }
```